# Show element after time in attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom, timer

Lets say that I have **n** elements with attribute **data-show-after="miliseconds"**

I want to display elements after the time from **data-show-after**

Example:

```
<div class="animate-template" data-show-after="1000">
  Show me this element!
</div>

<div class="animate-template" data-show-after="2000">
  Show me this element!
</div>

<div class="animate-template" data-show-after="15000">
  Show me this element!
</div>
```

What would be the best approach? To go through all element with the class name **animate-template** and create the timer for each of them or to create a timer with the biggest value (for all elements) and then check when the time.
If time from attribute of element is the same as current time in timer -> show the element

I will need also for hidding elements, adding incomming and outgoing animations, so need to keep that in mind too.

```
<div class="animate-template" data-show-after="15000" data-hide-after="1000">
  Show me this element!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example. I put 5s as value you can change it.

```js
  setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('hide-1').className = 'hide';
    }, 5000);
```

```css
 p {
        opacity:1;
        transition:opacity 500ms;
    }
    p.hide {
        opacity:0;
    }
```

```html
    <p id="hide-1">OHAI!</p>
```

Comment: I know to create example that you provided. My question is what is the best way to apply the same functionality but for more elements with different time.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

With some small modifications you can achieve what you need.

Also, [here](https://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)'s an article that contains some suggestion how to approach the topic. It explains how to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: I'm not using jQuery, just Vanilla JS